# Convert .caf file to normalised floating point array Objective-C/C

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I've managed to record audio using the `AVAudioRecorder` in Linear PCM format which is written to disk in .caf format. Not a problem.

I would now like to read the file and convert it into a normalised array of floats (i.e. each float between -1 and 1). I've tried the following:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
float *cData = (float *)malloc(data.length);
[data getBytes:cData length:data.length];
```

This gives an array of floats, (mainly between -1 and 1 but with some odd HUGE numbers in there also). Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Extended Audio File Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/) for reading audio files to PCM. The reason you are getting garbage is because you are interpreting the file header as samples. This API parses all of that for you. If you did want to do it manually you would have to find the starting point of your samples in your data, but I would recommend against it.